# Associative array, file names refering to the path, for dmenu

Tags: bash

And I started playing with dmenu and it seems such an automation for almost every thing. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with bash and it should be on my list.

I have a folder for my markdowns with subfolders containing my files. I'm trying to have a script to show them in dmenu while using an alias.

If the path to a file is

```
/home/user/docs/markdown/practice01/rmd/network.rmd
```

I would like to have

```
network
```

as an option in my dmenu. So when I choose

```
network -----> /home/user/docs/markdown/practice01/rmd/network.rmd
```

Here is my broken script. There are a few things I'm missing.

1. This way I get full path on my dmenu which i don't need. I tried to read about associative arrays but I can't figure it out in bash.
2. This script works but in case I decide to ESC and exit, still it opens up an empty vim in my directory. Hence, I should know if statements huh!

```
#!/bin/bash 

DMenu=("dmenu -l 10 -i -nb "#eaeaea" -sb "#E53935" -nf "#474747"")
cd ~/docs/markdown/
target=$(find -type f -name '*.rmd' | $DMenu)
st vim "$target"
```

I made a little example. But the problem is that it is a manual work to add each file, which definitely we don't wanna do right!

```
#!/bin/bash 

declare -A dotfiles
dotfiles[i3]="/home/user/dotfiles/i3/.config/i3/config"
dotfiles[vimrc]="/home/user/dotfiles/vim/.vimrc"
list=("i3\nvimrc")
target=$(echo -e $list | dmenu -i -nb "#eaeaea" -sb "#E53935" -nf "#474747")
st vim "${dotfiles["$target"]}"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associative arrays can be weird...  but returning output to a variable makes it easier to manipulate as any other string in bash, as shown in the example below:

```sh
prefix="$HOME/git/notes"
suffix=".md"

shopt -s nullglob globstar
item=( "$prefix"/**/*${suffix})               # Search *.md in all dirs/subdirs
item=( "${item[@]#"$prefix"/}" )              
item=( "${item[@]%${suffix}}" )               # Removes '.md' string from item name

result=$(printf '%s\n' "${item[@]}" | dmenu)

[[ -n $result ]] || exit                      # exit if nothing is found

gedit "${prefix}/${result}.md"                # Open file by adding again '.md'
```

When the percent sign (%) is used in the pattern `${variable%substring}`, it will return content of the variable with the shortest occurrence of substring deleted from the back of the variable.

Listed below for reference are 2 examples I wrote, one in Bash and the other in Python, for managing pass and markdown notes with dmenu:

- [dmenu-pass.sh](https://gist.github.com/fsilveir/ecd4049be0b50c1773d1bceeb5a71b9d)
- [dmenu-launch.py](https://github.com/fsilveir/dmenu-launch)

Also, listed below are a couple nice articles that might help you out:

- [The weird, wondrous world of Bash arrays](https://medium.com/@robaboukhalil/the-weird-wondrous-world-of-bash-arrays-a86e5adf2c69)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: Thank you, straight forward, I'm motivated to learn some more

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting some code in an array, use a function!

```
my_dmenu() {
    dmenu -l 10 -i -nb "#eaeaea" -sb "#e53935" -nf "#474747"
}
```

If your markdown files are all in the same folder (and not in subfolders), you certainly don't need `find`: use a glob instead! and if your files are in subfolders, use a glob instead (with the `globstar` shell option).

All in all:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_dmenu() {
    dmenu -l 10 -i -nb "#eaeaea" -sb "#e53935" -nf "#474747"
}

base_dir=~/docs/markdown

# Also, check the return code of cd!
cd "$base_dir" || { echo >&2 "Can't cd to $base_dir. Exiting"; exit 1; }

# Using a glob: use the shell option nullglob
shopt -s nullglob

files=( *.rmd )

# Check that there are some files found:
if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "No files found. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi

# Now we're ready to send the files to dmenu:
chosen_file=$(printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" | my_dmenu)

# If dmenu returns nothing: don't launch vim!
if [[ ! $chosen_file ]]; then
    echo "No files selected. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi

# Now you can launch vim!
st vim "$chosen_file"
```

---

If you also want to find the `*.rmd` files in subfolders: use instead:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar

files=( **/*.rmd )
```

---

Edit to address the requirement in your comment (and the edit of your question):

If you want to strip the `.rmd` suffix to show in dmenu, use:

```
chosen_file=$(printf '%s\n' "${files[@]%.rmd}" | my_dmenu)

# ...

st vim "$chosen_file.rmd"
```

The expansion `${files[@]%.rmd}` will strip the suffix `.rmd` from each field of the array `files`. Don't forget to add this suffix back when you edit the file (as shown in the last line).

Comment: Thanks it works. But the idea behind array is to get only file names in dmenu. Let's say if there is /home/user/markdown/practice1/rmd/network.rmd, I would like to get only "network" in dmenu. Somehow like the default dmenu_run.

Comment: I think since choose_file is used later to open the file later with vim, this does not open files but a new empty file. I will edit the question again with some code I did manually. But the point is I don't want to create lists manually. Give me a sec to edit.

Comment: @m3hdad the variable is `chosen_file`, not `choose_file`. And it does open the correct file!

Comment: right, my bad. Have a look at the script I have for dotfiles. That is my best with the array. it shows only i3 or vimrc in dmenu. Thank you for your script by the way.

Comment: @m3hdad but now I have no idea what you want to do! is your associative array given (in which case it's very simple to alter the script to make it take the associative array) or do you want to programmatically create this associative array (in which case you should specify how you want to create the key for a given file)?

Comment: I thought with the new edit at the end of question it is more clear. With the example dotfiles I use, manually I create an array, use a file name as key and it is linked to the path. so later at the end of the code when key is called I can have the file opened and dmenu shows only the key. The script for dotfiles which works but I have to create the array manually when I add a new file. yea?

Comment: @m3hdad and how about the `.rmd` files?

Comment: I thought it should be the same logic. Correct me if I am wrong. You have two lists. The first one is the path of all files. The second list (which is created from the first) contains the filenames only. Now you would associate each file name to each path. You pass the list with file names to dmenu. To open the file, at the end, you use the chosen file name and pass it as the key to the file path list.

Comment: @m3hdad you will hardcode your dotfiles in the script (as you shown) AND you ALSO want to have the `.rmd` files?

Comment: two different things

Comment: Oh, wait! I think I understand: you're problem is about your variable `list` that you don't want to populate by hand? If that's the case, just use `target=$(printf %s\n' "${!dotfiles[@]}" | my_dmenu)` and then the rest of the script in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't explain better. I guess I have to learn bash this weekend. But the thing is that there will be two different scripts, one for rmd files and one for dotfiles. Thanks anyway for your time.

Answer (score -2):

```
dmenuoptions="-l 10 -i -nb '#eaeaea' -sb '#E53935' -nf '#474747'"
st -e vim $(find ~/docs/markdown -type f -name '*.rmd' | dmenu $dmenuoptions)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: This returns exactly the output as my script.

Comment: The use of `eval` is not necessary... so I'd say it's an antipattern.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: i've test with `eval` removed, and it din't work.

Comment: @bruno: oh, i thought the answer is actually nearly the same as the script of m3hdad, so no need to explain [to him]

Comment: @m3hdad: strange. I've tested with my computer, and it worked. Sorry if it did not help. I assume that `st` is a terminal emulator (like `xterm`).

Comment: @m3hdad: it's really strange if it does not work for you. I've tested again, and it worked. Actually, I am [also] a `suckless.org` fan: I am using `st`, `dwm`, `dmenu` as tools for everyday work. Note: DONOT remove `eval`.

Comment: When I say that `eval` is not necessary, it's because you can do without: just remove the useless quotes you have. Now, putting a command in a variable is considered very bad practice (you know, it's pretty much only in Lisp that code is data; in other languages, code and data are separate things). I guess you got downvoted for lots of reasons! lack of explanation, and bad coding practice. Btw, I didn't downvote your answer; I'm now just trying to make sure you understand your mistakes so that (hopefully) you can fix them.

Comment: use dmenuoptions